# DevExpress LayoutView cardchange

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

i have a XtraGrid with and LayoutView. I use carousel to show my cards in this view. Is there a possibility to react on a "ActiveCardChanged" event or sth. like this. I just found "FocusedRowChanged" but this just react if i click the active card.

regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use the [LayoutView.VisibleRecordIndexChanged](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsLayoutLayoutView_VisibleRecordIndexChangedtopic) event. This event is raised when Layout View is scrolled and the index of the currently visible card is changed.